# What happened to the Stack Overflow layout?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

I was looking through some old questions trying to find bad answers to fix for editing and flagging and I came upon Stack Overflow question *[Closing a modal box with an iframe inside the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139354/closing-modal-box-with-iframe-inside-the-iframe)*.

It completely breaks the Stack Overflow layout. I can't even see the entire question to flag to mods attention. When I checked the same question in different browsers I got a message:

> We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP
>   address right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

Can a moderator review it to fix the issue?

This is happening in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. So it has to be something in the code in the question.

Comment: It's iframes all the way down.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but I can't edit it. It is hidden in the frame.

Comment: Yeah, I can't get to any edit or delete link either.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You guys. Just go to the `edit` route directly. :)

Comment: [I can](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1139354/edit)...but I do not dare to fix it. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I did, but this crazy "Anna Lear" person beat me to it by seconds. :P

Comment: @TimStone Oh my god, she's so annoying.

Comment: woah. trippy. stackception, etc. http://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ4Fl.png

Comment: @AnnaLear You and your fancy address bar incantations...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a code sample gone wrong. I fixed the formatting on it and all's right with the world again.

[balpha's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135089/155160) covers the rest.

Comment: Shouldn't the iframe stuff be escaped somehow? It looked like the post actually rendered those (until it failed somewhere).

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, it did. I had no idea we allowed `<iframe>` tags. We probably shouldn't. (And apparently we don't, since it's been 3 years since that question was posted. :))

Comment: thanks for fixing it so fast. for a second I thought I broke SO...not really. :)

Answer (score 12):

<s>Apparently back in 2009 when this answer was posted, the sanitizer wasn't... quite sane. Since the HTML is only generated on edit, you were looking at the HTML generated *back then*. A no-op edit would have fixed that (but of course Anna's edit made more sense in this case).</s>

You can see at https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1139354/2 (which is always rendered on the fly) that this issue has been fixed since then, so these days, this won't happen happen anymore.

The above is the *usual* answer for cases like this, but in this cases, it's not true. This was actually a *current* bug in the link-rot remapper. Fixed now.